# R MLR package: Stop makeClassifTask from dropping empty factor levels for testing set

Tags: r, mlr

I have a binary classification problem involving categorical predictor variables `Var1` & `Var2`:

```
> head(traindata)

#  ID   Var1 Var2 response
# 1 101   -2   0      0
# 2 201    0  -1      1
# 3 301    0  -2      0
# 4 401   -1   0      0
# 6 501    0  -1      1
```

The training set includes all `-2,-1,0` as levels of `Var1` but the testing set does not include `-1` as an input in `Var1`.

I did ensure that `Var1` contains all the levels in the testing set:

```
testdata$Var1 <- factor(testdata$Var1, levels = levels(traindata$Var1)
```

So the blank factor level does exist even though test data does not include `-1` in its records.

But when I try to create a task for the test set using:

```
testtask <- makeClassifTask(data = testdata, target = "response", positive = "1")
```

I get a warning stating the empty factor levels were dropped for columns: `Var1`

I tried setting the `fixup.data = "no"` parameter as well. It gives the following error:

```
testtask <- makeClassifTask(data = testdata, target = "response", positive = "1", fixup.data = "no")

# Error in (function (cn, x)  :
#   Column 'Var1' contains empty factor levels.
```

PS: I'm not resampling the testing data on my own, it's an external data set for which I do not know the response variable.

Also, I did recode dummy values for the response variable in the test set before creating the task.

Comment: Why are you making a task out of test data?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the empty factor level? It won't change anything, and some learners break with empty factor levels.

Comment: @missuse So if I am not mistaken, to predict using the mlr package an object needs to be of the class 'Task'. 
It throws an assertion error if I try to use a dataframe with the `predict()` function.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I need the levels to be same in the testing data set otherwise I get the following error when I try to predict using the test task in which levels are dropped:                         

`Error in predict.randomForest(.model$learner.model, newdata = .newdata,  :Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.`

Comment: You don't need a task object to get predictions with mlr, you can use a data frame. In general, use a single task and a resample description that partitions the data as you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post this as an answer since you did not understand my comment. Here is a reproducible example using data set Sonar from mlbench:

```
library(mlr)
library(mlbench)
library(caret)

data(Sonar)
```

split to train and test sets:

```
ind <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train.Sonar <- Sonar[ind,]
test.Sonar <- Sonar[-ind,]
```

train.Sonar and test.Sonar are data frames.

Make the task, learner and train:

```
task <- makeClassifTask(data = train.Sonar, target = "Class",  positive = "R")
lrn <- makeLearner("classif.rpart", predict.type = "prob")
mod <- mlr::train(lrn, task) #caret trains masks mlr train 

pred <- predict(mod, newdata = test.Sonar)
pred
#output
Prediction: 41 observations
predict.type: prob
threshold: M=0.50,R=0.50
time: 0.00
   truth     prob.M    prob.R response
2      R 0.86956522 0.1304348        M
3      R 0.86956522 0.1304348        M
6      R 0.86956522 0.1304348        M
13     R 0.07692308 0.9230769        R
22     R 0.11111111 0.8888889        R
25     R 0.07692308 0.9230769        R
... (#rows: 41, #cols: 4)
```

If you just do

```
pred <- predict(mod, test.Sonar)
```

then there is the error you mention:
    Error in predict(mod, test.Sonar) : 
      Assertion on 'task' failed: Must have class 'Task', but has class 'data.frame'.

since the functions assumes the data frame is passed as the task argument.

From the help of `predict.WrappedModel`:

> object [WrappedModel] Wrapped model, result of train.
>
> task [Task] The task. If this is passed, data from this task is
>   predicted.
>
> newdata   [data.frame] New observations which should be predicted. Pass
>   this alternatively instead of task.

Comment: Ah! It was a stupid mistake. Thanks for clarifying that. Yeah got it to work now. It was because of the `predict()` function itself. I should have included 'newdata' while listing out argument value.

Answer (score 1):

give the below parameters. You need to use `check.data` along with `fixup.data`. Hope this helps :)

**Syntax:**

```
testtask = makeClassifTask(data = testdata, target = "response", positive = "1",fixup.data = "no",check.data = FALSE)
```